# Jquery random words in array without repeating

Tags: jquery, random, append

I need to display random words in div without repeating the word.

Example: 
b
a
c
d

Not:
b
a
b
c
d
d
a
a
c

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
words = ['a','b','c','d'];
function doSomething() {}
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            $("#container").append("<div class=\"conversation\">"+thisWord+"<div class=\"conversation\">");
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
});
```

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188735/jquery-random-words-without-repeating/26188808.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the displayed letter from `words` using `.splice()` and stop displaying letter if there is nothing left in `words`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  words = ['a','b','c','d'];
  $(function() {
    rand = setInterval(function() {
      var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $("#container").append(thisWord);
      // Remove the displayed letter from words
      words.splice(words.indexOf(thisWord), 1);
      // If there is nothing left in words, clear the interval.
      if (words.length == 0) {
        clearInterval(rand);
      }
    },800);
  });
});
```

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p5npy1m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the `words` array using [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), then you can [`.splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) to remove each element you add. Then, when the array is empty you can clear the interval:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var words = ['a','b','c','d'];

    $(function() {
        //Create Copy
        var wordsSpliced = $.extend(true, [], words);

        //Save Interval Variable
        var intervalAddWords = setInterval(function() {
            //Clear Interval if all words shown
            if (wordsSpliced.length == 0) clearInterval(intervalAddWords);

            //Remove random word from wordsSpliced
            var thisWord = wordsSpliced.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsSpliced.length), 1);
            $("#container").append(thisWord);
        },800);
    });
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/05bbjtgc/1/

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm wondering why this code doesn't suit your purpose? (Also wondering how the exact same concept gets posted later and upvoted more, but that's another story.)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
words = ['a','b','c','d'];
var used = new Array();
var int = null;
$(function() {
  int = setInterval(function() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var thisWord = words[r];
        words.splice(r,1);
    $("#container").append(thisWord);
        if(words.length == 0) {clearInterval(int);$("#container").append(' DONE');}
  },800);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
words = ['a','b','c','d'];
function doSomething() {}
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            $("#container").append("<div class=\"conversation\">"+thisWord+"<div class=\"conversation\">");
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
});
```

I need to display random words in div without repeating the word.

Example: b a c d

Not: b a b c d d a a c