# Jquery random words without repeating

Tags: jquery

I need to display random words in div without repeating the word. The random words will append a div every random seconds (3-5 seconds). If all value in array displayed in div, alert will do.

Example:

```
b
a
c
d
ALERT('DONE')
```

Not:

```
b
a
b
c
d
d
a
a
c
```

MY code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
words = ['a','b','c','d'];
function doSomething() {}
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            var thisWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            $("#container").append("<div class=\"conversation\">"+thisWord+"<div class=\"conversation\">");
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

  var getRandom = function() {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    // grabs word and removes it from the array
    return words.splice(idx, 1)[0];
  };

  var appendIfMore = function() {
    var word = getRandom();
    if (!word) return; // all done

    $('<div class="conversation"/>')
      .text(word)
      .appendTo('#container');

    var delay = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(appendIfMore, delay);
  };

  // start appending stuff
  appendIfMore();

});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zogibujutiya/1/edit)