# JQuery append text with multiple elements but different value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append in conversation a div and h4.
I want the div convo-list to append text from array while i want to append custom text in .

On my code, the text on div convo-list and h4 are same. help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var getRandom = function() {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    return words.splice(idx, 1)[0];
  };

  var appendIfMore = function() {
    var word = getRandom();
    if (!word) alert('a');

    $('<h4>Name:</h4><div class="convo-list">').text(word).appendTo('.conversation');

    var delay = Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 500)) + 100;
    setTimeout(appendIfMore, delay);
  };
  appendIfMore();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
$('<h4>Name:</h4><div class="convo-list">').text(word).appendTo('.conversation');
```

to:

```
$('.conversation').append($('<h4>').text("Name:"), $('<div>').addClass('convo-list').text(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a random item in your array more nicely this way:

```
var getRandom = function() {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)]
};
```

And you have to fetch two different `word` so you can't save it into one variable only!:

```
var appendIfMore = function() {
    var wordConvo = getRandom(),
        wordName = getRandom();

    $("<h4/>", { html: "Name: " + wordName }).appendTo(".conversation");
    $("<div/>", { class: "convo-list", html: wordConvo }).appendTo(".conversation");

    var delay = Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 500)) + 100;
    setTimeout(appendIfMore, delay);
};
```

Hope it helps !

I created a JSFIDDLE for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5o2uoqbL/1/

EDIT: I just saw you wanted two different words for name and convo..see my updated JSFIDLLE that does exactly what you want !

Comment: `words.length` isn't the length of the words in the array; it's the length of the array itself.  The majority of the code in question is actually from an answer I provided on a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188735/jquery-random-words-without-repeating/26188808#26188808).

Comment: mmm you're right. I guess I didn't drink my coffee properly yesterday morning :) How come the person asking the question isn't accepting one answer and asking several times for the same question ?